# Splunk: Assigning variables

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have some data in splunk im trying to create a dashboard for. I am unsure how to assign a variable name for the 2 pieces of data im looking to extract.
My data looks like

```
From 5 new registrations, 4 emails were confirmed
```

I am able to search this data very easily with the following query

```
search "From * new registrations, * emails were confirmed"
```

How do i assign a variable to each of the asterisks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There likely are a few ways to do that.  I like using regular expressions and the `rex` command.

```
index=foo "From * new registrations, * emails were confirmed"
| rex "From (?<fromCount>\d+) new registrations, (?<emailCount>\d+) emails were confirmed"
```